# Preserve Nested Array Structure When Converting to String, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

When I create a nested array, say:

```
let x = [[0, 1], 2, [3, [4, 5]]];
```

and convert it to a string with .toString():

```
x.toString();
-> "0,1,2,3,4,5"
```

It doesn't preserve the nested structure of the array. I would like to get something like:

```
x.toString();
-> "[0,1],2,[3,[4,5]]"
```

Is there any smarter way of doing this other than looping through elements of x, testing if an element is an array etc.?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(x)`?

Comment: I hadn't thought about using stringify, and then I could just substring out the first and last brackets...

Comment: `JSON.stringify(x).slice(1, -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON.stringify and replace

```
 ^\[|\]$
```

[image]

```js
let x = [[0, 1], 2, [3, [4, 5]]]; 

let final = JSON.stringify(x)

// with regex
console.log(final.replace(/^\[|\]$/g,''))

// without regex
console.log(final.slice(1, -1))
```

Comment: Or just do a substring via `slice`?

Comment: I'll accept this in a minute when it will let me :)

Comment: I hadn't thought about using regex, I was just going to substring or slice like @Li357 commented. That's an interesting approach.

Comment: @Li357 yeah fair thing to do, add  that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Or possibly use a generator to build up a string manually:

```
 function* asNested(array) {
    for(const el of array)
      if(Array.isArray(el)) {
         yield "[";
         yield* asNested(el);
          yield "]";
      } else yield el.toString();
 }

 const result = [...asNested([[1, 2], [3, 4]])].join("");
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated compared to the above approach, and seems like it would use more time and computer resources, this is essentially the approach is said I wouldn't like in my question.

Comment: More complicated, yes, not necessarily slower.